# I had windows, fedora, ubuntu on my computer, i uninstalled ubuntu and i am stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, screen, fedora

I recently uninstalled ubuntu and i cannot access my fedora os because im stuck in a screen called GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta...

What i did was deleting the ubuntu partition from fedora
How can I recover this and access fedora.

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the sequence with details what and when you installed something and then how you uninstalled something.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using GParted or any partitioning software to delete OSes because doing this leaves the bootable grub files on your ESP/Boot sector (or something like that).

Insert a live Ubuntu DVD into your machine and install boot-repair and/or os-uninstaller using a terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install os-uninstaller boot-repair
```

Then just launch either of these tools using the sudo command in the terminal

If this does not work then you may need to go into your UEFI/BIOS settings and select the "Windows Boot Manager" from there